# Applescript to extract YouTube Livestream Video ID

Tags: macos, url, video, youtube

I want to develop an Applescript to extract youtube live stream video ID using the Channel ID.

Currently, I'm doing it manually as Youtube changes live stream video ID time to time. 
For an example, I'm practising following;

1. Open https://www.youtube.com/embed/live_stream?channel=UCu7cGbQEMgGk8TD0ZYucM5g
2. Right-click on the player and select "Copy video URL"
3. This URL is used to an Applescript I wrote to automate Livestreamer. (This script is given below.)

As Youtube changes this URL time to time, following script has to be changed the time to time. My intention is to automate the whole process.

```
-- Shraddha TV and Radio Recorder --
-- Developed by Anoma --
set pathToShraddha to ((path to downloads folder as text) & "Shraddha:")
set outputExtension to ""
set ls to ""
set sourceURL to ""
set con to ""
set windowInfo to ""
set theTime to ""
set endTime to ""

display dialog "Shraddha TV or Radio" buttons {"TV", "Radio", "Cancel"} default button 1
if result = {button returned:"TV"} then
  set outputExtension to ".ts"
  set sourceURL to "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1yv7JjMP4Dw"
  set ls to "livestreamer"
  set con to "480p -o"
else if result = {button returned:"Radio"} then
  set outputExtension to ".mp3"
  set sourceURL to "http://92.222.236.128:8006"
  set ls to "ffmpeg -i"
  set con to "-c copy"
else
  return
end if

set fn to (setFileName(outputExtension))

display dialog "Record now or later?" buttons {"Now", "Later", "Cancel"} default button 1
if result = {button returned:"Now"} then
 set endTime to text returned of (display dialog "Please set the time to end recording. (Leave 'hhmm' if you want to record continuously.) " with title "Timer" default answer "hhmm" buttons {"Cancel", "Set"} default button 2)
 set windowInfo to recordMedia(ls, sourceURL, con, (POSIX path of pathToShraddha as string), fn)
 finishTime(endTime, windowInfo)
else if result = {button returned:"Later"} then
 -- get time to be set---
 set theTime to text returned of (display dialog "Please set the time to start recording." with title "Timer" default answer "hhmm" buttons {"Cancel", "Set"} default button 2)
 if ((theTime as string) is equal to "hhmm") then
    display dialog "Time is not set correctly"
    return
 end if
 set endTime to text returned of (display dialog "Please set the time to end recording. (Leave 'hhmm' if you want to record continuously.) " with title "Timer" default answer "hhmm" buttons {"Cancel", "Set"} default button 2)
 display dialog (getTimeInHoursAndMinutes())
 display dialog theTime

 set i to 0
 repeat while (getTimeInHoursAndMinutes()) is less than theTime
    if (i = 0) then
        set i to (i + 1)
        recordMedia("", "", "", "", "")
    end if
    delay 60
end repeat
finishTime(endTime, (recordMedia(ls, sourceURL, con, (POSIX path of pathToShraddha as string), fn)))
else
 return
end if

-- This method generates the file name 
on setFileName(outputExt)
set fileName to do shell script "date +'%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S'"
set outputExt to the outputExt as string
set fileName to ("STV_" & fileName as string) & outputExt
return fileName as string
end setFileName

-- This method gives the current time in "hhmm" format (24hr) 
on getTimeInHoursAndMinutes()
set timeStr to time string of (current date)
set hrStr to (characters 1 thru -10 of timeStr as string)
if ((count hrStr) is less than 2) then
    set timeStr to ((0 & timeStr) as string)
end if
set ampm to (characters -2 thru -1 of timeStr as string)
if ((ampm as string) is equal to "PM") then
    if ((hrStr as integer) is less than 12) then
        set hrStr to (((hrStr as integer) + 12) as string)
    end if
else
    if ((hrStr as integer) = 12) then
        set hrStr to (0 as string)
    end if
    if ((count hrStr) is less than 2) then
        set hrStr to ((0 & hrStr) as string)
    end if
end if
set mStr to (characters 4 thru 5 of timeStr as string)
set timeStr to (hrStr) & (mStr)
return timeStr as string
end getTimeInHoursAndMinutes

-- This method Record the stream --
on recordMedia(ls, sourceURL, con, pathToShraddhaString, fn)
tell application "Terminal"
    set windowInfo to do script "caffeinate -i " & ls & space & sourceURL & space & con & space & pathToShraddhaString & fn
    activate of windowInfo
end tell
return windowInfo
end recordMedia

-- This method end recording --
on finishTime(endTime, windowInfo)
if ((endTime as string) is equal to "hhmm") then
else
    repeat while (getTimeInHoursAndMinutes()) is less than endTime
        delay 60
    end repeat
    tell application "Terminal"
        -- reopen
        activate of windowInfo
        --tell application "System Events" to keystroke "q"
        tell application "System Events" to keystroke "c" using {control down}
    end tell
end if
end finishTime
```

Could you please help me in developing the script to automate the extraction of the Livestream URL every time I run the script?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer given by Capitainos @ Superuser.

It works really fine.

```
Property LivestreamURL : {}
-- set youtube_channel to choose URL -- just remove comment tag to choose this option
set youtube_channel to "https://www.youtube.com/embed/live_stream?channel=UCu7cGbQEMgGk8TD0ZYucM5g"
tell application "Safari"
   launch  -- background OR use 'activate' if preferred    
   open location youtube_channel
end tell
-- wait for Safari to  load the webpage
if load_webpage(20) is false then return

tell application "Safari" to set end of LivestreamURL to do JavaScript "document.links[0].href" in document 1
   set this_ID to item 1 of LivestreamURL
   set channel_ID to (characters 51 thru -1 of youtube_channel) as string
   set video_ID to (characters 33 thru -1 of this_ID) as string

-- return LivestreamURL -- or;
return return & "Channel ID : " & channel_ID & linefeed & "Video ID     : " & video_ID & linefeed & linefeed

-- This is the Handler 'load_webpage'
on load_webpage(timeout_variable)
    delay 2
    repeat with i from 1 to the timeout_variable
        tell application "Safari"
            if (do JavaScript "document.readyState" in document 1) is "complete" then
                return true
            else if i is the timeout_variable then
                return false
            else
                delay 1
            end if
        end tell
    end repeat
    return false
end load_webpage
```